# iOS: When is cellForRowAtIndexPath called? Or do tags get updated?

Tags: ios, tags, tableview

I'm starting to get confused. I'm using a FetchedResultsController for my tableview data. In each cell I have a button and a textfield tagged with the indexPath.Row in the cellForRowAtIndexPath method:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    //Data model and cell setup
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"MainCategoryCell";
    MainCategoryTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    MainCategory *mainCategory = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    /* ... */

    cell.title.tag = indexPath.row;
    cell.iconButton.tag = indexPath.row;

    return cell;
}
```

Now my row move method is a bit more complicated for the Fetched Results controller. However I'm pretty sure the tags don't get updated after the moving. Is that normal and is the cellForRow method only called after creating a new cell? Do I have to update the tags myself in the move method? And how could I access there the tag properties of the objects within the cells?

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)sourceIndexPath
      toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)destinationIndexPath;
{
    // Process the row move. This means updating the data model to correct the item indices.

    //reordering has been defined in the CoreDataViewController so the
    //FetchedResultsController doesn't mess up the reordering since he would update
    //the fetched results permanently while reordering
    self.reordering = YES;

    //Makes only a mutable copy of the array, but NOT the objects (references) within
    NSMutableArray *fetchedResults = [[self.fetchedResultsController fetchedObjects] mutableCopy];

    // Grab the item we're moving
    NSManagedObject *resultToMove = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:sourceIndexPath];

    // Remove the object we're moving from the array.
    [fetchedResults removeObject:resultToMove];
    // Now re-insert it at the destination.
    [fetchedResults insertObject:resultToMove atIndex:[destinationIndexPath row]];

    // All of the objects are now in their correct order. Update each
    // object's displayOrder field by iterating through the array.
    int i = 1;
    for (MainCategory *fetchedResult in fetchedResults)
    {
        fetchedResult.position = [NSNumber numberWithInt:i++];
    }

    // Save
    NSError *error = nil;
    [self.budgetDatabase.managedObjectContext save:&error];

    // re-do the fetch so that the underlying cache of objects will be sorted
    // correctly
    [self.fetchedResultsController performFetch:&error];

    self.reordering = NO;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is normal that the tags won't get updated when you move cells.  Since all cells have the possibility of being shifted, simply reload the table view to have it regenerate the tags for your button and text box.

```
[tableView reloadData];
```

Comment: Shouldn't the fetched results controller do that automatically?!

Comment: According to Apple's documentation "Instead, you must call performFetch: to reset the state of the controller then reload the data in the table view (reloadData)."  So looks like you have to reload the data after calling performFetch: in the tableView:MoveRow:toIndexPath method

Comment: Don't really understand it from the documentation but it works. Can you maybe explain it? Sorry I'm new to the whole CoreData stuff and I sometimes find the FetchedResultsController confusing...somehow it monitors and somehow he doesn't...

Comment: How can I accept a comment as answer? Of course I'll do that :-) Hm and if I reload the data the cellForRowAtIndexPath method get's called and so the tags are updated correct?